# JPA native query to find record of current date

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
@Query(value = "select * from Capping_Audit_Capture;\r\n"

        +"where datepart(year, captured_time) = ?2;\r\n"
        +"and datepart(month, captured_time) = ?3;\r\n"
        +"and datepart(day, captured_time) <= 1 and check_point_id=?4 and line_id=?5 ", nativeQuery = true)
```

What is wrong with these query? I want to fetch all record of current date, getting exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forget a `space` right after the *positional parameters*. Try to separate the *positional parameters* and the *semicolon* like the example below.

```
@Query(value = "select * from Capping_Audit_Capture;\r\n"

        +"where datepart(year, captured_time) = ?2 ;\r\n"
        +"and datepart(month, captured_time) = ?3 ;\r\n"
        +"and datepart(day, captured_time) <= 1 and check_point_id=?4 and line_id=?5 ", nativeQuery = true)
```